# How to get region-name from DAG in MWAA

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I would like to know how to get a region name like ap-northeast-1 from DAG in MWAA.
Is it possible to get it?

We can get region name from config file. However, we would like to refer it without config file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom environment variable like [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/configuring-env-variables.html#configuring-env-variables-customizing) or use the MWAA ECS environment variable. Below are available on our workers.

- AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
- AWS_REGION=eu-west-1

and you can call os.environ["AWS_REGION"] in your dag.

Answer (score 0):

you can use python code to get env vars :

[DOC AWS : ENV VARS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/mwaa/latest/userguide/using-startup-script.html#:%7E:text=d%27autresAWS%20services%20dans.-,AWS_DEFAULT_REGION,-%E2%80%94%20D%C3%A9finit%20laAWS%20r%C3%A9gion)

```
 import os
# Get environment variables
Region_1 = os.getenv('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION')
Region = os.getenv('AWS_REGION')
```